# spring cloud auto refresh config server property

Tags: spring-cloud

I have configured spring cloud config which picks up property from Github. If I post to `/refresh`, I am also able to get the updated value in my application.

Now  I want to get properties updated automatically. That means I don't want to hit refresh API to get the changes reflected in my application from Github property file to my application.

Do I need to implement Rabbitmq and cloud bus for it or there is any other simple way to do it?
Also there document says that we need to add a dependency on the spring-cloud-config-monitor library for push notification.
http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_push_notifications_and_spring_cloud_bus
But I did not find any such dependency in maven to be added. Not sure if my understanding is wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a Config server with Spring Cloud Bus and RabbitMQ (or Kafka or Redis) support.

RabbitMQ with the following exchange:

**name**: springCloudBus

**type**: topic

**durable**: true

**autoDelete**: false

**internal**: false

The config server would send data to the topic once it receives push events from Git (Github, Bitbucket, GitLab) via a webhook to http://<config-server>/monitor

And a client application with Config and RabbitMQ libraries, subscribed to the previous exchange to receive messages of the properties that need to be refreshed.

More could be found in my blog at: http://tech.asimio.net/2017/02/02/Refreshable-Configuration-using-Spring-Cloud-Config-Server-Spring-Cloud-Bus-RabbitMQ-and-Git.html with a brief explanation of the configuration, logs and full source code for the Config server and client app.

Answer (score 0):

They are not generally available yet. You need to add http://repo.spring.io/milestone/ as a maven repository and use a milestone release.

Comment: Thanks spencergibb for your response.

Comment: I am not able to understand overall concept of Cloud bus. To create a simple demo(Helloword kind of) for Cloud bus, what are the minimum implementation I need to do. I already have a config server at github, and eureka server at my local machine. Please guide.Other example in spring-cloud-samples seems complicated.