# Spring Cloud Configuration - auto-enable Refresh Endpoint & Git monitoring

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

### Questions

I am starting to learn Spring Cloud starting with Spring Config.  There are two basic questions as I have to get me onto the next step in my learning process (moving on to Service Discovery via Consul).

1. How do I auto-enable the `/refresh` endpoint to POST to?
2. Is there a way to automatically monitor for updates in Git?

For #1 I implemented my own `@RestController`/`@RequestMapping` but none of the tutorials I was following mentioned that.  I checked my Maven configuration and it matches what the samples were providing but it's not popping up.

I found a post for the second question here:
[spring cloud auto refresh config server property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564275/spring-cloud-auto-refresh-config-server-property).  I was just wondering if there were any updates since November 2015 on this.

Both of these things seem to be exceedingly handy and will be directly intertwined with my Consul learning as I can push configuration updates automatically to everyone that is registered as a service.  Once I get there I can work on the restarts too, but that is later.

### Updates

I got an answer to #1.  I had botched my dependencies configuration in my Maven module.  After triple-checking the configuration it turns out it was just pilot error.  Still working on #2, though - if anyone has any updates it would be appreciated.

Comment: english is not my first language.. you mean automatically when you say aromatically ? :) (no need to reply in comments, just fix it in the question)

Comment: For 2, I think this will help you - http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.1.3.RELEASE/#_push_notifications_and_spring_cloud_bus

Comment: @nurgasemetey - can you post that as the answer and I will accept it.  that worked like a charm

Comment: Ok, I will do it but you know I didn't do it myself, just searched for reference guide. Look at Liping Huang's answer, if it is same, accept his answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For #1, Spring cloud config intrdouced the `@RefreshScope` annotation which will expose the `/refresh` endpoint (over HTTP or JMX)

For #2, after '/refresh', spring cloud config will take the latest git commit, For the config changes, essentially there are two ways, 1) pull the changes 2) push the changes, spring cloud bus approach is based on the rabbitmq to push the config chagnes.

**Reference**

[Refresh Scope](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/docs/1.0.x/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope)

Answer (score 1):

For GIT updates try to go through this documentation [spring-cloud-config-push-notifications](https://spencer.gibb.us/blog/2015/09/24/spring-cloud-config-push-notifications/) and do not forget to install ngrock. Also if you just need to refresh on git commit then you do not even need cloud-bus project just config should be enough. Hope this helps.